# why do I need std::condition_variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency

I found that `std::condition_variable` is very difficult to use due to spurious wakeups. So sometimes I need to set a flags such as:

```
atomic<bool> is_ready;
```

I set `is_ready` to `true` before I call notify (`notify_one()` or `notify_all()`), and then I wait:

```
some_condition_variable.wait(some_unique_lock, [&is_ready]{
    return bool(is_ready);
});
```

Is there any reason that I shouldn't just do this: (Edit: Ok, this is really a bad idea.)

```
while(!is_ready) {
    this_thread::wait_for(some_duration); //Edit: changed from this_thread::yield();
}
```

And if `condition_variable` had chosen a waiting duration (I don't know whether this is true or not), I prefer choose it myself.

Comment: You don't need the atomic; a simple `bool` is sufficient if the notify calls are done with the mutex locked.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can code this either way:

1. Using atomics and a polling loop.
2. Using a `condition_variable`.

I've coded it both ways for you below.  On my system I can monitor in real time how much cpu any given process is using.

### First with the polling loop:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

std::atomic<bool> is_ready(false);

void
test()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(30));
    is_ready.store(true);
}

int
main()
{
    std::thread t(test);
    while (!is_ready.load())
        std::this_thread::yield();
    t.join();
}
```

For me this takes 30 seconds to execute, and while executing the process takes about 99.6% of a cpu.

### Alternatively with a `condition_variable`:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

bool is_ready(false);
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;

void
test()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(30));
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    is_ready = true;
    cv.notify_one();
}

int
main()
{
    std::thread t(test);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    while (!is_ready)
    {
        cv.wait(lk);
        if (!is_ready)
            std::cout << "Spurious wake up!\n";
    }
    t.join();
}
```

This has the exact same behavior except that during the 30 second execution, the process is taking 0.0% cpu.  If you're writing an app that might execute on a battery powered device, the latter is nearly infinitely easier on the battery.

Now admittedly, if you had a very poor implementation of `std::condition_variable`, it could have the same inefficiency as the polling loop.  However in practice such a vendor ought to go out of business fairly quickly.

**Update**

For grins I augmented my condition_variable wait loop with a spurious wakeup detector.  I ran it again, and it did not print out anything.  Not one spurious wakeup.  That is of course not guaranteed.  But it does demonstrate what a quality implementation can achieve.

Comment: I've tested you code and your claim are true. But I think its because your cup happened to be idle. I've replaced `this_thread::yield()` with `this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1))`, and the process is taking 0.0% cpu too.

Comment: Yes, if you have a natural and moderate amount of work you must do anyway during the polling loop, then maybe that is the best solution for you.  That's what the atomics are there for if you need them.  But if you find yourself trying to decide upon an optimum time to sleep before polling again, perhaps you should test out the condition_variable solution and see how that works for your use case.

Comment: @Mike: but now you are waiting on average .5 milliseconds (~1 million machine cycles!) before your consumer realizes that is_ready is now true.  With the condition_variable you burn no cpu and probably get notified to wake up and check the condition in just a few thousand machine cycles.

Comment: Good example, it worked out of the box. Just one thing: The test function doesn't need the unique_lock.

Comment: @Alex:  If `main` and `test` were actually in different threads, `test` must lock the mutex prior to modifying `is_ready`.

Comment: @CCoder:  Your question is ambiguous.  There are two implementations in this answer.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Sorry about that. My question was regarding the second implementation with condition_variable usage.

Comment: @CCoder: In the second implementation it would be wasteful to make `is_ready` have type `atomic<bool>`.  In this code, `is_ready` is always read and written under the protection of the locked mutex `m`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Oh! Yes. I missed the lock on the writing thread. Thanks for you patience.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Thank you for this answer--very informative.  In the second example are there advantages to is_ready being read and written under the protection of the locked mutex *instead* of being declared as atomic<bool>?

Comment: @bRadGibson:  Yes.  The second example obviously has the benefit of low-energy consumption, and to achieve that you need the `mutex` and `condition_variable`.  Since those are needed anyway, it is free to manipulate `is_ready` under the `mutex`.  One should only pull out the sharp and dangerous knife called `atomic` when there is a clear benefit in doing so. When doing code reviews, when you see `atomic`, it is time to get a fresh cup of coffee, and really concentrate on the code. Spend an hour instead of 5min. If you don't need `atomic`, don't put your code reviewer through that extra effort.

Comment: do you need `is_ready` to be volatile or the compiler is smart enough to compile it correctly?

Comment: @Nick:  As long as `is_ready` is `std::atomic<bool>` (as shown in the first demo) or is both read and written under the protection of the mutex `m` (as shown in the second demo),  then it does not need to be `volatile`.  Making it `volatile` would either have no impact, or be a pessimization.  In C++, `volatile` is most useful for reading/writing memory-mapped I/O ports, and is not useful for inter-thread communication.

Comment: This answer is a great starting point for experimenting with `std::condition_variable`. I've rarely had so few growing pains with new concepts, but the concept of a conditional variable is something I've wanted for a long time. I'm glad to see it's possible directly through the `std`.

Comment: I'm just learning about multithreading and suppose the second example is prone to a race condition. It would occur if `test()` returns before the execution of `main()` progressed to the locking of mutex `m` in its second loc. Am I right, or is there something I overlooked?

Comment: After the construction of the `unique_lock` in `main`, there is no point in `main` where `m` is unlocked, except during the `wait`.  `condition_variable` is designed such that the beginning of the `wait`, and the unlock are atomic, and the end of the `wait` and the lock are atomic.  The two actions can't be interrupted until both are complete.

Comment: I just stumbled upon this answer and was wondering, in the second implementation, why is it necessary to call `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);` in `test()`? If I understand it correctly this should be avoided according to the cppreference for [std::condition_variable::notify_one()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one), I guess it just doesn't have a noticable effect here because the destructor of `lk` in `test()` gets called shortly afterwards?  
I'm also wondering how time-accurate the second implementation is compared to the first one?

Comment: The `lk` in test could be avoided by using an `atomic` for `is_ready`.  Without the atomic or the `lk`, the write to `is_ready` is not sequenced before the notify, and main could be signaled and still read false.  There's a great deal of literature on the order of unlock vs notify, and I encourage you to read it.  You can add a timer to measure the time between the signal and main waking.  For me on a non-busy computer, compiled with optimization, it ranges from 40 to 96us.  The spec allows for this inevitable delay.

Answer (score 38):

The purpose of `std::condition_variable` is to wait for some condition to become true.  It is *not* designed to be just a receiver of a notify.  You might use it, for example, when a consumer thread needs to wait for a queue to become non-empty.

```
T get_from_queue() {
   std::unique_lock l(the_mutex);
   while (the_queue.empty()) {
     the_condition_variable.wait(l);
   }
   // the above loop is _exactly_ equivalent to the_condition_variable.wait(l, [&the_queue](){ return !the_queue.empty(); }
   // now we have the mutex and the invariant (that the_queue be non-empty) is true
   T retval = the_queue.top();
   the_queue.pop();
   return retval;
}

put_in_queue(T& v) {
  std::unique_lock l(the_mutex);
  the_queue.push(v);
  the_condition_variable.notify_one();  // the queue is non-empty now, so wake up one of the blocked consumers (if there is one) so they can retest.
}
```

The consumer (`get_from_queue`) is *not* waiting for the condition variable, they are waiting for the condition `the_queue.empty()`.  The condition variable gives you the way to put them to sleep while they are waiting, simultaneously releasing the mutex and doing so in a way that avoids race conditions where you miss wake ups.

The condition you are waiting on should be protected by a mutex (the one you release when you wait on the condition variable.)   This means that the condition rarely (if ever) needs to be an `atomic`.  You are always accessing it from within a mutex.