# the following problem is a multi threaded problem. i need to print the 'Done' in the next line without using '\n' or 'endl'

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

Q1. You will implement the function f(n) = n(n+a)(n-b) through multi-threading.  The main thread will take three numbers n, a and b as input. There will be 4 additional threads. Main thread will pass the number n as parameter to the first thread and the second threads. The numbers a and b will not be passed as parameter to the first and the second threads. The first thread will calculate n(n+a) and print it (according to given sample). The second thread will use the n(n+a) value calculated by the first thread and calculate n(n+a)(n-b) and print the result (according to the given sample). The third thread will print “Done” after the above-mentioned outputs. The fourth thread will print necessary line breaks between outputs of other threads.

**Sample input:**

```
5
2
3
```

**Sample output:**

```
Result1 = 35
Result2 = 70
Done
```

**My code:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
using namespace std;
int a ,b, temp;

void func1(int n)
{
    cout << "Result_1 = ";
    temp = n*(n+a);
    cout << temp;

}

void func2(int n)
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
    cout << "Result_2 = ";
    cout << temp*(n-b);
}

void func3()
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(50));
    cout << "Done";
}

void func4()
{
    //cout <<"New Line" << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    a = 2 , b = 3;
    thread t1(func1,n);
    t1.join();
    thread t2(func2,n);
    //this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    thread t3(func3);
    thread t4(func4);

    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
}
```

The above code outputs:

```
Result_1 = 35
Result_2 = 70Done
```

But I want:

```
Result_1 = 35
Result_2 = 70
Done
```

Comment: The goal of the question is presumably to teach you about thread synchronization, which you are not doing here (`sleep` is **not** an acceptable solution). This is the main problem you need to fix. Please refer to whatever course/material you have this task from.

Comment: an answer would really spoil the learning for you, hence just a hint: remember what you learned about mutexes or other synchornisation mechanisms

Comment: Concerning threads which have to wait on each other: Sounds you should have a look at [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)s as well. The alternative might be busy loops with `std::atomic` but... No, I would recommend the former. ;-) There is a nice answer for [SO: why do I need std::condition_variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16350623/7478597).